# how to iterate through a treemap within a treemap java

Tags: java, iteration, treemap

hello i have this treemap :

```
TreeMap<String, Info> words = new TreeMap();
```

the class info and node is this :

```
 public static class Info {

  int totalOccurrences;
  int maxTF ; 
  ArrayList<Node> pointer;
  //ArrayList<String> files;  // document frequency --> files.size()
  TreeMap<String, Integer> files;

  Info(String selected) {

       totalOccurrences = 0;

       pointer = new ArrayList<Node>();
       pointer.add(new Node(selected));

       //files = new ArrayList<String>();
       files = new TreeMap();

       maxTF = 0 ; 
  }

 }
```

So what I want to do is to get the integer values of the files TreeMap for each
one of the words Treemap elements

In other words how do I iterate through the TreeMap within the TreeMap?

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
TreeMap<String, Info> words = new TreeMap();

public static class Info {

    int totalOccurrences;
    int maxTF;
    ArrayList<Node> pointer;
    //ArrayList<String> files;  // document frequency --> files.size()
    TreeMap<String, Integer> files;

    Info(String selected) {

        totalOccurrences = 0;

        pointer = new ArrayList<Node>();
        pointer.add(new Node(selected));

        //files = new ArrayList<String>();
        files = new TreeMap();

        maxTF = 0;
    }

}

public void test() {
    // For each Info in the `words`
    for (Info i : words.values()) {
        // For each file in `files`
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : i.files.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " e=" + e);
        }
    }
}
```